# Does matlab know to find the location of the file by the file name and set it as a current directory?

Tags: path, directory, set

I'm trying to build a function that takes the user's file and imply automatic calculations. Can I set the user's file location as a current directory only by knowing its name?

Answer (score 0):

`str = which(item)` returns the full path for item in the string, str.

[Reference](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html)

`cd(str)` changes the current folder to str.

[Reference](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html)